# Django decorator_from_middle type_error

Tags: python, django, middleware

I am trying to exclude middle ware from some of the  views in Django and I got the problem.

This is the class of middleware

```
class JWTAuthorisation(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # before view
        token = request.headers.get('x-auth-token')
        if not token:
            return HttpResponse("No access token provided", status=401)

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

I am using this @ to include the middleware to view

```
  @decorator_from_middleware(JWTAuthorisation)
  def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
```

This is the error

```
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\LoreProject\users\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from users import views
  File "E:\LoreProject\users\views.py", line 75, in <module>
    @decorator_from_middleware(JWTAuthorisation)
  File "E:\LoreProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 111, in decorator_from_middleware
    return make_middleware_decorator(middleware_class)()
  File "E:\LoreProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 116, in _make_decorator
    middleware = middleware_class(*m_args, **m_kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'get_response'
```

**Update**
I changed my class to

```
class JWTAuthorisation(object):

   def process_request(self,request):
       print("hello")
       return None
```

I am getting this

```
 File "E:\LoreProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "E:\LoreProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 127, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "E:\LoreProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 37, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment *I am using this @ to exclude the view*. The `decorator_from_middleware` is used to apply middleware to a view, it doesn't exclude it.

Comment: Okay it makes sense , my fault, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.decorators.decorator_from_middleware) for `decorator_from_middleware`

> Given a middleware class, returns a view decorator. This lets you use middleware functionality on a per-view basis. The middleware is created with no params passed.
>
> It assumes middleware that’s compatible with the old style of Django 1.9 and earlier (having methods like process_request(), process_exception(), and process_response()).

Your middleware needs to be the "old style"

Comment: It did not help. I changed to this
 def process_request(self,request):
.....
return None 

and getting 
File "E:\LoreProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 37, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Comment: Can you update your question with your new middleware?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the error was this:
middle was set up in settings and I wanted to exclude it. 
So If remove middlle from settings.py and change middle  to  1.9 django style this will work.
Thank you !